# Give Files.ReadWrite.All permission for a specific group/team to an application

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, authorization

**Context / Problem**

I'm implementing a headless daemon that needs access to some Sharepoint resources (`Files.ReadWrite.All` permission) via the Microsoft Graph API.

The challenge is to give this daemon access to resources of only a specific group/team.

**Approach 1**

The obvious solution is a machine-to-machine authentication using the "client credentials flow" as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview).

The problem is that I don't see a way to limit the `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission to a specific group or team, which is a security issue in our case.

**Approach 2**

The other approach I considered is creating a separate user for my deamon, which is a member of only the group my daemon needs access to.

But signing in using a specific user means that I get redirected to the microsoft login form, which is obviously not suitable for a headless daemon.

**Question**

What's the best way to solve this? Is there something I missed in my approaches above? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Hi Robert, one way to do this is, create a user account in the required group. Create a new "public client" app and enable group claims to flow in the access token to be issued. Add following delegated permission: `Files.Read.All` to the public client app, and grant admin consent - so that interaction is not needed. Followed by this, you can get a token for this user using resource-owner password grant workflow with the scope set to the `Files.Read.All` in the daemon app.

Answer (score -2):

•   You can surely go ahead with your approach 1 as it is the most correct way of granting the required permissions to a daemon application via Microsoft Graph API to the Sharepoint resources. But in that approach, you can surely restrict access to that daemon app to a certain group for sure as below: -

a)  Register the Sharepoint online application in your Azure AD in Enterprise Applications. Once done, open the application which wants access to sharepoint resources in ‘App registrations’ in your Azure AD and grant ‘Microsoft Graph API’ and Sharepoint online the required permissions through ‘API permissions’ section as below: -
[image: Registering the app]

b)  Once the permissions such as ‘Files.Readwrite.All’ and other permissions to access your daemon application are consented for, open your daemon application in ‘Enterprise Applications’ by clicking on the ‘Go to Enterprise Applications’ link as below: -
[image: Enterprise applications]

c)  Then, click on ‘Users and groups’ option under ‘Manage’ section and add the group that you want to give access to this application as below. Once the group required has been added in here, the members in this group only will be able to access the resources in Sharepoint online.
[image: Adding groups]

Thus, in this way, you can assign a group access to the sharepoint resources through a daemon application via Microsoft graph.

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. Your suggestion limits access to the app to specific groups/users. I need to limit what the app can do. I was able to solve it using delegated permission and resource-owner password.